# Is there anyway to save push notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

When user a sends a push notification to user b, user b will receive the notification, but once they click on it the payload from that notification is gone. Instead when user b opens the notification, the payload in the notification will get saved to parse, so he can view all the notifications that were sent to him. It's like a notification history. Below is my code to send notifications. I need help on how to save the payload within those notifications, so users can look at notification history.

```
func pushNotifications(){


    let userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    userQuery.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: Array(setOfSelectedFriends)) 

    let pushQuery: PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()!
    pushQuery.whereKey("user", matchesQuery: userQuery)

    let push = PFPush()
    push.setQuery(pushQuery)
    push.setMessage("\(username!) wants you to meet them at \(location!)")

    push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock {
        success, error in

        if success {
            print("The push succeeded.")
        } else {
            print("The push failed.")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably should do it the other way around, make a table where you save new "MeetingInvites" and whenever a new entry gets added send a push notification to the corresponding user.

Make the push notification a side effect of the actual new entry. Not make the entry a side effect of the push notification.

That would also save you the trouble of having to deal with notifications that get lost - maybe the receiving user opens the app, then *something* crashes and your push notification and all the connected data would be lost.

A little bit more detail: Create a column for the location, one column for the "requesting" user and one for the "partner". In your code, set the currentUser as the requesting one, and the partner as  the ... well ... partner. Then either on your client device or on the server create a push message. In both cases send the push message to the "partner".

Comment: Ok, yeah I think that would be a better approach. On the parse end how would I structure the class? like with the entries. Say user a wants to send user b a "message" saying meet me at x location. How would I structure the class so when user a sends it, it will appear on user b's device.

Comment: @stackerleet I included a small paragraph regarding that.